# jQuery to Select elements that does not contain a certain value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using the following jQuery code to count the number of text fields that have a value that is the same as its title attribute.

```
$(".textfield").val( $(".textfield").attr('title') ).size();
```

**Problem:** How do I count the number of text fields that **do not** have a value equal to its title attribute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, the code you post is not doing what you say it does. This:

```
$(".textfield").val( $(".textfield").attr('title') ).size();
```

Will *set* the value of *all* elements with class ".textfield" to the title of the first ".textfield" element's title attribute, and then return a count of all of them.

You need to compare the return of the `.val()` method (with no parameter it returns the current value) with the return of the `.attr('title')` method. You can do this with `.filter()` and then check the `.length` of the resulting jQuery object:

```
$('.textfield').filter(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    return $this.val() == $this.attr('title');
}).length;
```

And then to get a count of those where the value is not equal just do the same thing except with `!=` instead of `==`. So:

```
$('.textfield').filter(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    return $this.val() != $this.attr('title');
}).length;
```

(Note that `.length` will give you the same count as `.size()` but without the overhead of a function call.)

Comment: it's `textfield` not `textbox`

Answer (score 1):

I would use `filter()` and then access the `length` property of the returned set.

```
var count = $('.textfield').filter(function() {
                return $(this).val() != $(this).attr('title');
            }).length;
```

You could also probably get away with the body of `filter()` as `return this.value != this.title`.

Comment: Touché! I was just posting that :)

Comment: @gdoron Sounds like a micro optimisation, not worth the extra line of code.

Answer (score 0):

- use the `filter` function.
- use `length` property of the selector

---

```
var length = $('.textfield').filter(function() {
                return this.value != this.title;
             }).length;
```